# ASP Buttons not working after changing ActiveViewIndex

Tags: c#, asp.net, multiview

I'm using MultiView to build a multi step form. The next button works on the first step (ViewOne) but then both the next and back buttons do nothing at the next step (ViewTwo).

I don't know if there is any clue in the below code or you need to see more?...

```
 <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView2" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
 <asp:View ID="ViewOne" runat="server">
 </asp:View>
 <asp:View ID="ViewTwo" runat="server">
 </asp:View>
 </asp:MultiView>
 <asp:ImageButton ID="btnBack" runat="server" ImageUrl="/assets/back_button.jpg"  OnClick="btnBack_Click" /> 
 <asp:ImageButton ID="btnNext" runat="server" ImageUrl="/assets/next_button.gif" OnClick="btnNext_Click" />
 <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" ImageUrl="/assets/submit_button.gif" OnClick="btnSend_Click" />
```

Code behind....

```
protected void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MultiView2.ActiveViewIndex--;
    }

    protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MultiView2.ActiveViewIndex++;
    }

    protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnSubmitClicked(e);
    }
```

Ok more code...

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
        base.OnLoad(e);
     PopulateSomeField();
    }

protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        btnBack.Visible = MultiView2.ActiveViewIndex > 0;
        btnNext.Visible = MultiView2.ActiveViewIndex < MultiView2.Views.Count - 1;
        btnSubmit.Visible = MultiView2.ActiveViewIndex == MultiView2.Views.Count - 1;
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no error there. It works just fine for me.

**Test2.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test2.aspx.cs" Inherits="test2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView2" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
         <asp:View ID="ViewOne" runat="server">
            One
         </asp:View>
         <asp:View ID="ViewTwo" runat="server">
            Two
         </asp:View>
         </asp:MultiView>
         <asp:ImageButton ID="btnBack" runat="server" ImageUrl="/assets/back_button.jpg"  OnClick="btnBack_Click" /> 
         <asp:ImageButton ID="btnNext" runat="server" ImageUrl="/assets/next_button.gif" OnClick="btnNext_Click" />
         <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" ImageUrl="/assets/submit_button.gif" OnClick="btnSend_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Test2.aspx.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class test2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        //PopulateSomeField();
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        btnBack.Visible = MultiView2.ActiveViewIndex > 0;
        btnNext.Visible = MultiView2.ActiveViewIndex < MultiView2.Views.Count - 1;
        btnSubmit.Visible = MultiView2.ActiveViewIndex == MultiView2.Views.Count - 1;
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }

    protected void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MultiView2.ActiveViewIndex--;
    }

    protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MultiView2.ActiveViewIndex++;
    }

    protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("submitted");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, I edited and added some more code. Incredibly quick response btw!

Comment: @Brian - What is `PopulateSomeField()`? Is that relevant?

Comment: @Brian - I commented out `PopulateSomeField()` and it still works fine for me.

Comment: thanks for looking man. I'm really stuck now. I put break points on the btnNext, btnBack etc but the don't hit when in ViewTwo.

Comment: @Brian - I would comment out everything down to basically what I have above in the markup and in code and see if you can get it working bare bones.  Then add pieces back in one by one to see what causes the issue.